# A program to print the alternate letters of a word in one word. Like abc and ABC aAbBcC

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that asks the user to enter two strings of the same length. The program should then check to see if the strings are of the same length. If they are not, the program should print an appropriate message and exit. If they are of the same length, the program should print the alternate characters of the two strings. For example, if the user enters abcde and ABCDE the program should print out AaBbCcDdEe.

I have tried this but it does not work

```
t1 = input('Enter a string: ')
t2  = input('Enter another string: ')
run = True
while run:
    if (len(t1)!=len(t2)):
        run = False
elif (len(t1)==len(t2)):
    for i in range(len(t1),len(t2)):
        if (i%2 ==0):
            t1[i]+=t2[i]
            print(t1)
```

Comment: zip will do what you want

Comment: If `len(t1)==len(t2)`, then your `range(len(t1),len(t2))` will be empty and your loop won't run at all. Also, there's no reason for testing for even indices, and `t1[i]+=t2[i]` will fail because strings are immutable - you have to create a new string. Try to run this with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, it is possible to be more clever with building the string, but this maybe is the easiest to understand.

```
a = input("string a:")
b = input("string b:")

s= ""
if len(a) != len(b):
    print("Not same length!")
else:
    for i,k in zip(a,b):
        s += i+k
    print(s)
```

Here without rebuilding the string each time:

```
s= []
if len(a) != len(b):
    print("Not same length!")
else:
    for i,k in zip(a,b):
        s.append(i)
        s.append(k)
    print("".join(s))
```